# How to gain access to a ServletContext instance from any method?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets

Is there any way to get access to the ServletContext from a method without passing the ServletContext as an argument?

I need to have a generic Configuration class that can work on several environments and load the config in a way depending on the environment.

For example, when in a web app, i need to get the configuration from either web.xml or a config file stored in WEB-INF.

But in order to know if the app is running in a web app i need to gain access to the ServletContext somehow.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

Have a class that holds servlet context as static field initilize it from `ServletContextListener`